# Estimating coordinates to draw over image using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, coordinates

I need to draw two rectangles (or this could apply to any shape in general) of different colors on top of a diagram.
The MWE that I have this is. The code works, but I am unable to change the coordinates of the squares to accurately achieve my desired result. I have been drawing using the `tikzpicture`.

My `MWE` is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

     \begin{frame}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/sample.png}};
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (5.3,5.3) rectangle (8.4,8.4);
        \draw[green,ultra thick,rounded corners] (3.4,3.4) rectangle (8.3,8.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This `MWE` correctly draws the rectangles on top of the image, but they are incorrectly placed over it.

The desired result is along this line:

[image: desired result]
However, at the moment, I am achieving the following result:

[image: Actual Result]

Can someone provide insight on how to best estimate the coordinates that will help me get to my desired output?
This problem has been recurrent for me for several tasks - so I would like to understand how to calculate them.
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: @Tobi I don't think it is a duplicate, as my question is not in regards to drawing. I already have the code for that. My question is regarding to how to accurately calculate the coordinates. Similar, but they are, in fact, different questions.

Comment: @owwoow14 You can use the second part of the accepted answer and [the answer of Jake](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/32374) on that same question to normalize the coordinates of your image, such that the bottom left is (0,0) and the upper right is (1,1). Then you can draw a grid on top of your image and easily align the proper coordinates

Comment: @owwoow14 Alternatively, you can draw your graph with [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and use the `axis cs` coordinate system to accurately draw on your graph in the "natural" coordinates of the graph, i.e. whatever your axes are labeled with. As such, I think it is a duplicate, unless you can be more specific about what your problem is :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when I want to draw over an image, I first draw a grid with a proportional scale the image with foreach and the calc library.

Then I use these coordinates to draw

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (img)at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sample.png}};
        \foreach \xx in {0,1,2,...,9}{% 
        \draw[dashed] ($(img.north)!0.\xx!(img.north east)$)node[above]{0.\xx} --  ($(img.south)!0.\xx!(img.south east)$);
                \draw[dashed] ($(img.east)!0.\xx!(img.north east)$)node[right]{0.\xx} --  ($(img.west)!0.\xx!(img.north west)$);
        }
        \path ($(img.north)!0.1!(img.north east)$)|-coordinate(c1)($(img.east)!0.3!(img.north east)$);% c1: first corner
         \path ($(img.north)!0.82!(img.north east)$)|-coordinate(c2)($(img.east)!0.77!(img.north east)$);   %c2 : second corner
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (c1)         rectangle (c2);
%        \draw[green,ultra thick,rounded corners] (3.4,3.4) rectangle (8.3,8.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

use proportional coordinates used to change the scale of the image and maintain proper drawing

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (img)at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sample.png}};
    \foreach \xx in {0,1,2,...,9}{
    \draw[dashed] ($(img.north)!0.\xx!(img.north east)$)node[above]{0.\xx} --  ($(img.south)!0.\xx!(img.south east)$);
            \draw[dashed] ($(img.east)!0.\xx!(img.north east)$)node[right]{0.\xx} --  ($(img.west)!0.\xx!(img.north west)$);
    }
    \path ($(img.north)!0.1!(img.north east)$)|-coordinate(c1)($(img.east)!0.3!(img.north east)$);
     \path ($(img.north)!0.82!(img.north east)$)|-coordinate(c2)($(img.east)!0.77!(img.north east)$);
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (c1)         rectangle (c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding the grid really helps to visualize how the drawn figures move around the image.